# how to loop and shorten the code

Tags: javascript, loops

I have similar kind of codes but only a bit different. How to shorten this below code?

**Example Below**

```
var sms = document.getElementsByClassName("class-two");
sms.forEach(function(e) {
  e.style.width = 200 + 'px';
});

var sms = document.getElementsByClassName("class-one");
sms.forEach(function(e) {
  e.style.height = 100 + 'px';
});
```

The difference between the above is only the `class-one` and `class-two` and the two lines `e.style.width = 200 + 'px';`and `e.style.height = 100 + 'px';`, Can I use loop here and how?

Comment: instead of `e.style.width = 200 + 'px';` use `e.style.width = '200px';` - that saves 3 characters (x 2 = 6) - drop the `var ` before the second `sms =` there's another 4 characters ... 10 so far

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not an array so there is no forEach

Comment: Why are you setting the width directly on all these elements? What is the use case? Whatever you are trying to do could almost certainly be done much more easily with judicious use of CSS classes.

Comment: Take a look at **functions**. Essentially, they are parameterized computations, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Agreed, @torazaburo... What's the context for this?

Comment: Indeed Learning

Comment: If your objective is learning, which is admirable, then learn how to use CSS properly to avoid extensive JS logic to loop and do things that CSS already does for you.

Answer (score 3):

Adhering to the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), you could write a function to encapsulate your redundant code:

```
function setWidth(cls, attr, pixels) {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(cls)).forEach(function(e) {
    e.style[attr] = pixels + 'px';
  });
}
setWidth("class-two", "width", 200);
setWidth("class-one", "height", 100);
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` which does not possess the `forEach` method

Comment: @MasterBob - I didn't even notice the incorrect use of `forEach` in question!!

Comment: be aware that `Array.from` is very new

Comment: For ES5 we can write 
function setWidth(cls, attr, pixels) {
     Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(cls)).forEach(function(e) {
    e.style[attr] = pixels + 'px';
  });
}

Comment: True, or just a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array#forEach` and creating a function which can be called with the class, style attribute and value ..

```
function setThings(cls, attr, value) {
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName(cls), function(el) {
        el.style[attr] = value;
    });
}
setThings("class-two", 'width', '200px');
setThings("class-one", 'height', '100px');
```

However, even after fixing the questions misuse of `forEach`

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("class-two"), function(e) {
  e.style.width = '200px';
});

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("class-one"), function(e) {
  e.style.height = '100px';
});
```

is actually shorter code, unless the function (setThings) is named with a single character, then the first answer is shorter

Comment: I don't think this is semantically equivalent to the code provided by the OP.

Comment: one is height and another is width `e.style.width = 200 + 'px'` and  `e.style.height = 100 + 'px';`

Answer (score 1):

It's considered bad practice to set CSS styles directly on elements as you are doing, and it's not necessary. You can simplify your code greatly by intelligent use of CSS, reducing the amount of JS to essentially one line to toggle a class on a higher-level element which drives the width or height of the child elements, thereby eliminating any need for loops or functions. You'll have less code to write, debug, and maintain. Essentially, instead of finding all the elements with a particular class yourself in JS, you let the CSS engine do that, which is what it does for a living!

```js
const topElement = document.getElementById('top');
const buttonElement = document.getElementById('button');

function toggle() { topElement.classList.toggle('narrow'); }

buttonElement.addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

```css
.class-one, .class-two { width: 300px; height: 16px; }
.class-one { background: red; }
.class-two { background: blue; }

.narrow .class-one { width: 200px; }
.narrow .class-two { height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div class="class-one"></div>
  <div class="class-two"></div>
</div>

<button id="button">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

@qxz answer seems best.
But if you want to avoid function call, refer this:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.class-two,.class-one'), function(e) {
  if (e.className.includes("class-two")) {
    e.style.width = "200px";
  };
  if (e.className.includes("class-one")) {
    e.style.height = "100px";
  };
});
```

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vignz_pie/rwo9c6m6/) for you